# Is webservice call has Browser Support issue?

Tags: web-services

Recently i have faced one interview in which he asked me a question that-
Do you ever face a problem in calling web service from particular browser ?

So i want to know is web service has browser compatibility issue?

I already search in google but didn't find any particular answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still i didn't face any issue related browser compatibility in webservice.

I think there is no issue in browser compatibility in using webservice.

Regards
AB Vyas